# Volume Control Extremely Sensitive/Too Loud for Corsair 1500 USB Gaming Headset in Linux Mint

Tags: usb, audio, usb-device, volume, usb-audio

This headset works exactly as expected in non-linux operating systems (e.g. macOS, Windows) such that the volume control smoothly adjusts the loudness of the headset all the way from `0` to `100`.

In every version of Linux I've tried (e.g. Linux Mint), anything below 25% volume results in complete silence, and anything above 33% volume is ear-splittingly loud, leaving almost no resolution for fine-tuning.

I've tried using `alsamixer` and `pavucontrol` to explore the available volume levels, with no change in behavior.

How can I achieve fine-grained control of this USB headset in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I found through trial and error:

1. Open a terminal and run `pavucontrol`.
2. Navigate to the `Output Devices` tab.
3. ***CAREFULLY*** adjust the **Corsair Vengeance 1500 Analog Stereo** device volume to the **loudest** you would ever want.
4. Switch to the `Configuration` tab.
5. Change the profile of the **Corsair Vengeance 1500** device from `Analog Stereo Duplex` to `Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input`.
6. Switch back to the `Output Devices` tab.
7. You should now be able to smoothly adjust the volume of the **Corsair Vengeance 1500 Digital Stereo (IEC958)** device using the `Digital Output (S/PDIF)` port!